# Update all published posts at once

Tags: custom-post-types, database

I know this question has been asked a few times but I can't find one with an adequate answer.

I need to run through all my posts and update them as in -> go to the edit screen a press Update - as some values for custom field values have been updated automatically.

Is there anyway of doing this automatically?

Running `wp_update_post()` etc. does not do this. Nor does Bulk Edit update.

Any thoughts would be most appreciated.

Thanks,
D.

Comment: What is this other database table? What is the code that is running when you update? Is it a plugin?

Comment: Well it's not just the database table there are also other changes that need to happen automatically. Yes it's a plugin though. So I just need to understand really whether it's possible to run something that will emulate Edit -> Update for all posts

Comment: Does anyone know whether Bulk Edit -> Update uses a different hook than Edit->Update?

Comment: It depends on what hook the plugin uses to do its thing. You're going to need to ask the author for help if you're dealing with a 3rd-party plugin. Those are off-topic here.

Comment: So it wasn't just the database table update it was some custom field change too.

Answer (score 1):

I would have preferred to put this as a comment, but space does not allow for it so sorry about that. It might help you rather than being an answer. I am using 'product', but it could just as easy be 'post'.

```
function update_all()
{
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    $products_array = get_posts($args);
    if (!empty($products_array))
    {
        foreach ($products_array as $product)
        {
            echo "product : " . $product->ID;
            //Update whatever here, eg wp_update_post($product->id,$error);

        }
    }
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

As you have the product id for each product in a loop, you can get any meta or custom values for that product, and update them. I used this to bulk update prices for example. Obviously you would only want to run this from time to time, so I keep it remarked in the code. You could of course run it as a cron. I am a bit unclear on what you are trying to update. Looks to me like it's simply the publish date, which you could do in a loop.

I fail to see why wp_update_post in this loops wouldn't do it. Perhaps you need to enable displaying the errors when it runs.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct for updating fields automatically for sure. I guess the issue is more that when I open the edit screen other functions run that populate some of the custom fields. I was curious as to why the Bulk Edit didn't do the same. If that makes sense.

Comment: Ah ok. It could be as simple as a javascipt/jquery function runs to populate those files when opening, but they would never run when running a script. You would have to duplicate that functionality in your php code. You cannot get the javascript code to run serverside, which is where any automatic php script will run.